# google sheet single cell email notification

Tags: email, notifications, google-sheets, email-notifications

I am trying to create an email notification when a single cell or cell D28:D33 and L28:L33 display "Complete".

Below are some of the codes I was able to pull but it will only do email notification to any changes to the row or column. I need this code to only do it to specific cell.

So I have put together this code, but it seems like when i click play it goes through, but i still get emails whenever anything on the spreadsheet is edited.

```
    function sendNotification() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
      var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
      var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
      var range_bill_com = sheet.getRange("D28" || "D29" || "D30" || "D31" || "D32" || "D33");
      var test = 0;
      if (range_bill_com.getValue() == "Complete" && test == 0){
         var recipients = "username@email.com";
         var message = '';
         var subject = 'Update has been done to '+sheet.getName();
         var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit link to view changes ' + ss.getUrl() + ' changes have been made to row: «' + cell + '»';
         MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
      test = 1;
      }
      };
```

I am also trying to add a value to once the email has been sent the value changes from test = 0 to test = 1 so it doesn't resend the email again.